# Can a Swift Playground on iPad contain multiple source files?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift-playground

I'm just wondering if this is possible: I have a playground opened on Xcode with multiple .swift source files in it and accessible via a *public* accessor. Can the same be possible on iPad's Swift Playgrounds?

[image: Some .swift source files inside a .playground file]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.
On Apple's website they state:

> Because you’re working with real code, you can import and export
> directly between Swift Playgrounds and Xcode. So you can try out your
> ideas with the tool pros use to develop iOS and Mac apps.

[Tech Republic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-the-swift-playgrounds-ipad-app-to-code-on-the-go/) provide advice on how to achieve this:

> **Importing existing Playgrounds from Xcode**
>
> Importing Playgrounds from Xcode can be nice when you want to try your hand at coding on the go. To do this, you have two simple options.
>
> Store your documents in iCloud Drive. This is the easiest method and
> lets you access your iCloud Drive documents by tapping the + icon in
> Swift Playgrounds and selecting iCloud Drive or your other favorite
> cloud document storage solution, e.g., Dropbox. Email your documents.
> Once you've emailed a Swift document to yourself, open the email on
> the iPad, and tap the Playground file. You'll be prompted to select a
> share location—select the Copy To Playgrounds option.

Comment: Thank you, would you have any insight regarding creating this kind of playgrounds directly inside the iPad app?

Comment: Not directly inside the iPad app, but with the iPad (and no Mac), yes. I cloned a repo containing some Playgrounds projects with Working Copy, then using iOS 11 Files I copied the folder to my iCloud Drive > Playgrounds folder. Works like a charm!