# How to add AND USE source file(s) in iOS playground

Tags: swift

Refer to the documentation: [adding package to playground](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/playgrounds-ipad/itcdd72f72c4/ipados).  You can see on the sidebar a userModule and under it a shared code.swift i.e.

Pages
…
Source Code
Main
UserModule
— SharedCode.swift

- hello2.swift

But there is no example to use it.  I spend a whole morning and most example if not all are about the Xcode, but iOS playground.

How to do it?

Say in your main

```
hello()
hello2()
```

In the sharedCode.swift

```
func hello(){
   print(“hello world1”)
}
```

In the hello2.swift

```
func hello2(){
   print(“hello world -2-”)
}
```

---

Study all doc and finally understand what is required after trying several import

You cannot import the source itself.  It is not #h or module.

The closest is this [no example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012148/can-a-swift-playground-on-ipad-contain-multiple-source-files) and once again no example

Answer (score 0):

In main

```
import UserModule
hello()
hello2()
```

In the sharedCode.swift

```
public func hello(){
    print("hello world1")
}
```

In the hello2.swift

```
public func hello2(){
    print(" hello world -2-")
}
```

Import is the general way to import module (package as well it seems) and the key for those function you want to be used elsewhere, you have to make it public.

———-

Seems only you can have UserModule and hence the main is complete.

You can add Swift files and the name and content need not aligned. It will check all inside and include them.  And if you duplicate definition it will warn you.  If you miss or misspelt there will be a red dot.

And be careful difference between " and “.